# Random double between Double.MIN_VALUE and Double.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, random

Anyone got an idea of how to achieve this. I've tried the usual formula but I'm only getting positive numbers <= 10:

`Double.MIN_VALUE + Math.random() * ((Double.MAX_VALUE - Double.MIN_VALUE) + 1)`

Comment: Double.MIN_VALUE is positive.

Comment: This depends whether you want all doubles with an equal likelihood, or whether you want a rectangular distribution between -MAX_VALUE and MAX_VALUE.  In the former case, use Peter Lawrey's solution.  In the latter case, use eyalzba's solution.

Answer (score 8):

You could do this

```
private static final Random rand = new Random();

public static double getRandomDouble() {
    while(true) {
        double d = Double.longBitsToDouble(rand.nextLong());
        if (d < Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY && d > Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)
            return d;
    }
}
```

This will return any finite double with equal probability.

You can't just the the formula above as the `(Double.MAX_VALUE - (-Double.MAX_VALUE))` overflows to infinity. i.e. the range for all positive and negative double values is too large to store in a double.

Comment: What's the purpose of the while loop?

Comment: The while loop is there, because this could generate an invalid `double`.  If that happens, try again.  If it happens again, try again.  And so on.  As soon as you get a valid double, you jump out of the loop.

Comment: @PeterLawrey What about `NaN`?

Answer (score 3):

```
double d = Math.random() * Double.MAX_VALUE;
return Math.random() < 0.5 ? d : 0-d;
```