# Generate secure random double without overflow

Tags: java, random, cryptography, double, range

I want to generate a random, cryptographically secure double in a very large range, say [`-Double.MAX_VALUE`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884793/) to `Double.MAX_VALUE`.

Based on existing StackOverflow questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/363681/) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12395127/) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22110772/) [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680637/) [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723765/) [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21307702/)) you may think that using `min + new SecureRandom().nextDouble() * range` would suffice, but `Double.MAX_VALUE - -Double.MAX_VALUE` overflows and becomes infinite!

To solve that, [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39575303/) suggests using [`ThreadLocalRandom.nextDouble(min, max)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html#nextDouble-double-double-). While this method is indeed capable of spanning the range I need it to, this implementation is not cryptographically secure!

How can I *securely* generate a random number within such a large range?

Comment: How about `SecureRandom.doubles(min, max)`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? (With a `SecureRandom`.) https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079474/367273

Comment: @shmosel Using `doubles(-Double.MAX_VALUE, Double.MAX_VALUE)` will always generate the same value of 1.7976931348623155E308, though I do not understand why.

Comment: @NPE If I slightly change the implementation to accept a custom `min` and `max`, it definitely solves my problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. One of the requirements for cryptographic security is that the numbers should be indistinguishable from values selected uniformly at random.

If you choose 2<sup>64</sup> numbers in the range from −10<sup>308</sup> to +10<sup>308</sup>, then two adjacent numbers will be separated by the rather large distance of 2.0E+308 / 2**64, which is about 1.08E+289.

Since a double-precision number has a 53-bit significand, then most of these numbers will be indistinguishable anyway. For example, adding 1.08E+289 to 1.0E+307 has absolutely no effect when working with double precision arithmetic.

Even if you do manage to find a way of mapping 2<sup>64</sup> values into this range, you'll probably still be vulnerable to [birthday attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_attack). In general, you need at least 80 bits to provide a useful level of protection.

Comment: Wouldn't this mean that generating numbers from `0` to `Double.MAX_VALUE` is unsafe as well?

Comment: @FWDekker I think the best you can do is use [the method that NPE linked to in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20079474/367273). This won't give you a uniform distribution, and will need additional checks to handle special values like signed zeros and denormal values. I have no idea what your aim is, but I'm sure you would probably be better off working with random integers (preferably 80 or 128 bits) instead of faffing about with doubles.

Comment: You bring up a good point: What is my aim? I was reminded by another SO question that the range of integers representable by a double is _not_ continuous, something that I implicitly assumed. My aim is to securely generate a random value in the continuous integer range, which does not cause the problems I mentioned in my question.

Comment: The largest continuous range of integers that can be represented exactly in double precision floats is from -2^53 to +2^53. So you could, I suppose, generate a random integer in this range and convert it to a double. This range is rather too small for cryptographic applications, I think.

Comment: FWDekker: In fact, floating-point numbers are practically never used in security applications, with the exception of differential privacy and lattice-based cryptography.  Rather, security applications use random _integers_ instead.  Does your security use case rely on random _floating-point numbers_ rather than integers?